# Vietnamese font display error

Tags: fonts, 19.04

I am using Ubuntu 19.04 and I got this font problem: letters with certain accents looks really weird comparing to the rest.

It also appears in other apps like Chrome, Firefox, Spotify,... It didn't happened when I was using 18.04.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thank you.

[image: Font display error]

Comment: You may want to explain in English what the nature of the problem is. Maybe submit an image showing what it _should_ look like. If you do, also someone who don't speak Vietnamese might be able to help.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Thanks for the tips. I have updated my question.